# Make angular image-cropper functtion

Tags: angular, image

I need to make in angular like this:
http://bcabanes.github.io/angular-image-cropper/
but this demo is for angular 1, but now I need to do it for angular 8.
Anyone can help, please?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ngx-image-cropper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper) library.
Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/image-cropper).

Or

Use [image-cropper](https://alyle.io/components/image-cropper) library. Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lbaojjvdppm?file=app%2Fimage-cropper-example-03.component.html).

Comment: Thanks, friend. But I need to hide the cropper border and you can see in the demo (in question), we drag and drop the image in a fixed cropper, not move the cropper over the image.

Comment: @ndc_lara https://alyle.io/components/image-cropper

Comment: Awesome, it's quite similar to my requirements. Thank you so much @Adnan Ahmed

Comment: @ndc_lara Glad to help. Please accept my answer.